# Формирование чанка с помощью getResources

Tags: modx, шаблонизаторы

Добрый день, друзья! Только начал работать на системе ModX. Поставлена задача сформировать динамическую страницу в которой будут перечислены все работы (портфолио). Структура чистого html такова:

```
<div class="portfolio">
   <!-- row -->
   <div class="p_row">
       <div class="p_item item_long open" data-extend="p01">описание работы1</div>
       <div class="p_item" data-extend="p02">описание работы2</div>
   </div>
   <!-- /row -->
   <!-- row extend -->
   <div class="p_row_extend">
       <div id="p01" class="p_extend open left">скрытный блок для работы1</div>
       <div id="p02" class="p_extend right">скрытный блок для работы2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Как видно из структуры блоков, верстальщик сверстал таким образом, что в один блок класса=portfolio включены два видимых блока класса=p_item и скрытные блоки класса=p_extend. В jquery скрипте приписаны события клика по визуальным блокам портфолио, при которых открываются/скрываются невидимые блоки соответственного блока. Но суть проблемы в том, что ModX весьма ограниченно можно внедрять логику в чанки (html-шаблоны). Используя вызов getResources я написал следующий код:

```
<div class="portfolio">
[[!getResources? 
   &parents=`12`
   &showHidden=`1`
   &includeTVs=`1`
   &processTVs=`1`
   &tpl=`div_v`
]] 
</div>
```

В tpl (чанке) div_v я написал следующий код:

```
[[+odd:is=`1`:then=`
    <div class="p_row">
     <div class="p_item [[+tv.width_portfolio]] [[+tv.status_open]]" data-extend="[[+tv.id_block]]">
       <div class="pic">
         <img src="[[+tv.url_mini_picture]]" alt="">
       </div>
       <h3>[[+idx]] [[+tv.title_portfolio]]</h3>
       <p>[[+tv.prolog]]</p>
     </div>
    `:else=`
     <div class="p_item [[+tv.width_portfolio]] [[+tv.status_open]]" data-extend="[[+tv.id_block]]">
       <div class="pic">
          <img src="[[+tv.url_mini_picture]]" alt="">
       </div>
       <h3>[[+idx]] [[+tv.title_portfolio]]</h3>
       <p>[[+tv.prolog]]</p>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="p_row_extend">   
    <div id="[[+tv.id_block]]" class="p_extend open right">
       <div class="inner">
         <div class="pic">
           <img src="[[+tv.url_picture]]" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="info_wrap">
           <div class="info">
              <h3>[[+tv.title_portfolio]]</h3>
              [[+tv.first_content_portfolio]]
           </div>
           <p class="site">Сайт: <a href="[[+tv.url_site]]">[[+tv.url_site]]</a>
           </p>
           [[+tv.second_content_portfolio]]
           <p><a href="" class="btn">Подробнее</a>
           </p>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div> 
`]]
```

С помощью условного оператора (смотреть первую строку кода) я проверяю на четность/нечетность подгружаемого документа в чанк div_v. Если документ нечетный то формируется первая часть класса = p_row, в противном случае вторая часть этого divа с завершающим тегом. Но со скрытной частью класса p_row_extend есть проблема, по моему коду эта часть выполняется только в случае если попадает в четное условие блока, и соответственно выводит инфу только для четного документа. Как сделать так чтобы выводить в скрытном блоке и нечетный и четный документ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А нельзя было tplOdd использовать???

```
 Доступные параметры
Параметры шаблонизации

tpl
    Имя чанка, выступающего в качестве шаблона для ресурса. Если не установлен, свойства выдаются в виде списка для каждого ресурса
tplOdd
    Имя чанка, выступающего в качестве шаблона для ресурсов с нечетным индексом (см. параметр idx
tplFirst
    Имя чанка, выступающего в качестве шаблона для первого ресурса
tplLast
    Имя чанка, выступающего в качестве шаблона для последнего ресурса
tpl_N
    Имя чанка, выступающего в качестве шаблона для N-ного ресурса, например &tpl_4=`tpl4th`
tpl_nN
    Имя чанка, выступающего в качестве шаблона для каждого N-ного ресурса, например шаблон &tpl_n4=`tpl4th` будет применен к каждому элементу, порядковый номер которого кратен 4 Добавлено в версии: 1.4.1-pl
tplPath
    Дополнительный каталог для поиска чанков на основе файлов при использовании биндинга @FILE По умолчанию: assets_path + "elements/chunks/"
outputSeparator
    Дополнительные строки для разделения каждого ресурса после шаблонизации По умолчанию: "\n"
toPlaceholder
    Если установлен, присвоит результат в указанный плейсхолдер вместо вывода напрямую
toSeparatePlaceholders
    Если установлен, присвоит КАЖДОМУ результату отдельное имя плейсхолдера в виде суффикса из значения этого параметра и порядкового номера (начиная с 0) Добавлено в версии: 1.3.0
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но вопрос уже решен.